# Лагает Эмулятор

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор

Лагает эмулятор Android Studio, при запуске начинает зависать и не отвечать. Раньше было нормально, а щас лагает. Может надо почистить кэш, есть какие то советы?

Comment: Зайди в ADV-менеджер. создай новый. и посмотри на результат. если будет и новый лагать, то возможно проблема в хостовой ос.

Comment: Надо переустановить Intel HAXM. И образ надо выбирать x86. В этой связке у меня все летает.

Answer (score 0):

Есть 3 варианта как решить проблему с лагающим эмулятором:

1. Установить драйвер HAXM и запускать эмуляторы на образе x86/x64
2. Установить эмулятор [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) - в персональной лицензии и с образом работающим поверх виртуальной машины - летает
3. Решить вопрос кардинально и перейти на Linux/Ubuntu

Если в первом варианте скорость принять за 100 единиц, то во втором варианте скорость будет 200, а в 3-м все 400 единиц.

Я лично перешел на опцию №3